# Flex 4.6 TextInput with prompt on ios misbehaves

Tags: ios, apache-flex, prompt, textinput, autocorrect

On ios, the TextInput makes weirdness. The following code:

```
        <s:TextInput id="password" width="100%" displayAsPassword="true"
                     needsSoftKeyboard="true" 
                     prompt="Password"  
                     softKeyboardType="default"
                     returnKeyLabel="done"
                     autoCorrect="false"
                     skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"
                     />
```

When I select the textInput, the prompt disappears as expected but the first character is auto selected. When the second key is pressed, the first character is removed. This only happens when the first character is typed and the field has a prompt message. "autoCorrect" does not seem to do anything.

Does anyone know of a workaround to this issue? I looked at the SkinnableTextBase class but can't find any guilty code.

This issues started with Flex 4.6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After spending hours in the Flex code, I finally realised that Flex isn’t the problem. The issue happens with **Air 3.2** (also in **Air 3.3** beta). If I compile with **Air 3.1**, everything works fine.

I have tried various things and there seems to be no way I can fix it in **Air 3.2** +. I checked other projects of mine and it seems like all my applications compiled with **Air 3.2** have a similar issue :(

**[UPDATE]**

The problem is somewhere in **SkinnableTextBase.as** in **Flex SDK**.

When **textDisplay_changeHandler(event:Event)** is called, **invalidateSkinState()** causes the problem. If you set the skin's state to nothing (""), it works:

```
skin.currentState = "";
invalidateSkinState();
```

The problem is that the theme doesn't update properly (and it's a h@ck).

If you set **"showPromptWhenFocused"** to **false** in your CSS, the problem doesn't happen; the only side effect is that the prompt disappears when you have the **textInput** selected.

```
s|TextInput
{
    skinClass:ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin");
    showPromptWhenFocused: false;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Too bad that the issue is still very present in AIR 3.5. It's these little things that make Flex less and less viable for serious enterprise app development. Maybe Adobe ditched it because they saw that the framework wasn't really suitable for mobile in the first place. It just has too many flaws.

Comment: You saved my day, +1 for this, tnx. I would not agree that Flex is less and less viable for enterprises i would say is opposite. There is really a lots of movement lately with AIR SDK updates. You must know that Adobe is covering 2 biggest desktop and mobile operating systems out-there with only 1 SDK, no-one can do better, and no html5/whatever combination can beat that. iPhone5 and iPad Mini were supported just as they entered the market. I however agree that here and there you will find those little nasty bugs, but that's always a possibility with every framework out-there not just AIR SDK.

Comment: I don't see this mentioned yet; but most likely the issue is with StageText vs the Flash TextField.  Using the old TextInputSkin switches back to TextField

Answer (score 3):

Flying problem is solved for Textinput with spark skins with FB4.6 and Air3.5. I think the actual problem is from Air. But now the Softkeyboard is not activating when focused.

```
<s:TextInput id="mail"  softKeyboardType="email" skinClass="spark.skins.spark.TextInputSkin" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you scrolling the TextInput? If not you can use the new Flex 4.6 TextInput mobile skin.  The new skin utilizes StageText which may correct your problems.  Remove the attribute skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" and it should default to the new skin.

```
<s:TextInput id="password" width="100%" displayAsPassword="true"
                 needsSoftKeyboard="true" 
                 prompt="Password"  
                 softKeyboardType="default"
                 returnKeyLabel="done"
                 autoCorrect="false"
                 />
```

Note: StageText does not render properly if you scroll the TextInput and you must use the Flex 4.5 mobile skin as you currently are.

Comment: I'm not scrolling the text. You are correct about NOT using the "spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" skin. The problem is that if you don't use the mobile skin, StageText is drawn above everything else. Including Dialogs. That's just not cool :(

Comment: I must also mention that using the mobile skin and compiling with Air 3.1 works as expected. The problem only exist from Air 3.2 +. I was thinking that the problem could be with IOS, but the version of Air seems to be at the core of the problem. I really need to use Air 3.2 because of the stage3D functionality.