# Adobe Flash Air TextInput not working properly on IOS and Android

Tags: flash, mobile, air, mxml, textinput

I am using Air SDK 3.9 and trying to figure out solutions to the following issues with TextInput.

1) on IOS, the first character typed gets marked by clipboard controls eventually the second character overwrites the first one.  Don't know how to turn off clipboard controls.  IN android this doesn't happen.

2) on IOS and Android, all of a sudden (generally after switching views back and forth), attempt to focus by tapping on the textinput does not work.  soft keyboard does not popup either.

any ideas?

This is what I am using.

```
<TextInput id="emailAddress" textAlign="left" prompt="Enter your email address"       softKeyboardType="email" returnKeyLabel="next" focusEnabled="true" autoCorrect="false"  skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `skinClass` to `spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin`? (that class name is from memory, it may not be exactly right but it should have `mobile` in its path)

Comment: Yes, I added the block of code, but got supressed, updated it again above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the showPromptWhenFocused to false.
See: [Flex 4.6 TextInput with prompt on ios misbehaves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929470/2635569)

Within the textInput:

```
showPromptWhenFocused="false"
```

Or in a CSS style:

```
.customTextInputStyle{

        showPromptWhenFocused: false;
        skinClass: ClassReference("skins.CustomTextInputSkin");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a really weird related problem where a TextInput on a view was NOT clickable, so softkeyboard was not activiting. Turns out I was changing orientation, and set aspect ration and set display state on parent view.

If I set Aspect ratio after setting display state the TextInput was not clickable. The order of the below 2 lines was important.

Caused Text Input to NOT be clickable...

```
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);
```

Works OK...

```
stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

UPDATE:

turns out there's a better fix. It might be that the interaction is locked off.  Try:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```